# Can't spot the mistake in using "friend" function of another class C++

Tags: c++, friend

Yes I know that `private` modifier created in order to prohibit access to class data 
but isn't `friend` intended to allow special access to it?

> Compiler: 
>   main.cpp: In member function 'void C::blah(B&)': 
>   main.cpp:48:26: error: 'int B::a' is private within this context 
>   std::cout << obj.a << std::endl;

Everything below is implemented the way as it is in many tutorials. 
May be it's just a silly mistake I made and blind to spot.

```
class C;

class B {
private:

    int a = 2;

public:

    friend void blah(B& obj);

};

class C {
public:

    void blah(B& obj) {
        std::cout << obj.a << std::endl;  //*
    }

};
```

> *Member B::a is inaccessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a non-member function named `blah`, but not `C::blah` as `friend`.

You could change your code to the following, and note the order of the declaration and definition.

```
class B;

class C {
public:
    void blah(B& obj);
};

class B {
private:
    int a = 2;
public:
    friend void C::blah(B& obj);
};

void C::blah(B& obj) {
    std::cout << obj.a << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fAYqmmNkuDTi1F8u)